# Show different routes to user than actual in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-fullstack

I am working on a full stack web development using Angular, Node(Express) and mySQL. I want to show user some different route than what it actually is. How can I do that?
For example, this is my dashboard page.

```
http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard
```

I want it to be viewed as something else to the user like:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome 
OR
http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome/LandingPage
```

Meaning, this page can only be accessed if you enter the Url:

```
 http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard
```

and, if the user tries to access this page by entering the Url that is being shown to him:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome 
OR
http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome/LandingPage
```

then, he gets an error.

I have done this all in **app.routing.ts**. I just want to ask how can I do the above mentioned. To show that route to the user that actually doesn't exist.

For further clarification: When the user will open the page then it will be shown to him as "localhost:4200/#/Welcome". I want to just show the user this route. In my code, it actually should remain dashboard. In easy words, when the user enters the url: "localhost:4200/#/Welcome" it should throw an error because in code such route doesn't exist. It was just shown to the user as a kind of fake route. In actual, it should be "localhost:4200/#/dashboard" but, shows to user as "localhost:4200/#/Welcome"

Comment: in your routes.module, you'll have to update path: 'what the client should see' with component: component it needs to direct to. ex { path: welcome, component: dashboardcomponent}

Comment: You are right. I can do that. But, when the user will open the page then it will be shown to him as "http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome". I want to just show the user this route. In my code, it actually should remain dashboard. 
In easy words, when the user enters the url: "http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome" it throws an error because in code such route doesn't exist. It was just shown to the user as a kind of fake route. In actual, it should be "http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard" but, shows to user as "http://localhost:4200/#/Welcome" :)

Comment: My best suggestion would be to add both options in your routing module. This allows a user to enter any of the values.

Comment: @LotteLemmens I want to hide my real route from the user. Show just a fake route to him. I am not using route guard but trying to protect my routes in this way. Showing fake routes to user that are inaccessible when you try to access in the url. As I want to name them uniquely and different in my code from what is shown to user.

Comment: With normal routing this cannot be done. The url and their matching comonents ARE the navigation in Angular. Perhaps you can overwrite an httpinterceptor and then navigate to another component without redirecting, but I cannot help you there

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe using location will do the trick if I understood question right.

```
constructor(private location: Location){}
replaceState(){ 
  this.location.replaceState("/Welcome");
}
```

You will have to import Location module:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```